# Arduino IDE giving a blow to battery back-up of PC

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, ide

When I have *serial plotter* open in the Arduino IDE with serial communication going on, the fans of my PC go full speed. On checking I found that **Java(TM) Platform SE binary(32 bit)** is using about **29%** of the **CPU**.

This gives a big blow to the PC's battery back-up. Is there some way to reduce the CPU usage ?

> The IDE version I use is **Arduino 1.8.4**

```
OS : Microsoft Windows 10 Home (64 bit)

PC : HP Au620 TX (laptop)

processor : Intel i5 7th gen (7200)

RAM : 8GB
```

Comment: What sort of computer?  What OS?  You've left out a ton of detail here.

Comment: That's Java for you...

Comment: what battery backup?

Comment: @Majenko I doubt Java is to blame. One could write a busy loop in any language.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Indeed, but Java makes it easier for dumbass programmers to write terrible code.

Comment: try restarting Ardunio and not compiling anything before using the serial plotter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Arduino IDE in a virtual machine which allows CPU allocation. Set a strict limit on CPU resources in that VM, like 200..500 MHz.